# eject html content in bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i write this  code for put html in the popover:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="<div id='custom_tooltip_text' style='width: 300px; height: 250px; background-color: red;'>
<a href='#'>link 1</a>
<a href='#'>link 1</a>
<a href='#'>link 1</a>
<a href='#'>link 1</a>
<a href='#'>link 1</a>
</div>"    
<span class="badge" id="badge_message">5</span>
</span>
```

and result:
[image: result]

the html content eject in popover

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unset the `max-width` to your popover class :

**CSS**

```
.popover{max-width: inherit;}
```

**Bootply** : https://www.bootply.com/xLV7f6JHE5